# How to use setTimeOut to repeat a text?

Tags: javascript

When i click on "Add text" button and the input is empty a message is shown below and after 3 sec it's removed. After this whenever i click it does not show the message because I use `remove()` to remove the message. I want to show this message whenever I click on then button. And also how to position message without using absolute.

```js
const inputVal = document.getElementById("two");
const txtr = document.getElementById("one");
const btnr = document.getElementById("btn");
const dlt = document.getElementById("three");

function myFunction() {
  if (inputVal.value == "") {
    var msgs = document.getElementById("para");
    msgs.innerHTML = "Enter Something Here ";
    msgs.classList.add("okay");
    setTimeout(() => msgs.remove(), 3000);
  } else {
    const x = document.createElement("li");
    x.setAttribute('id', "demo");
    var y = document.createTextNode(inputVal.value);
    x.appendChild(y);
    txtr.appendChild(x);
    inputVal.value = "";
  }
}

function removeChild1() {
  var item = document.getElementById('demo');
  txtr.removeChild(txtr.lastChild);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.input-values {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 10%;
}

.input-values h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightsalmon;
}

.second input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.second button {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border: 2px solid lightcoral;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

.okay {
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 520px;
  left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-values">
      <h1>Add Some Text</h1>
      <ol class="txt" id="one">
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <input type="text" name="" id="two" placeholder="Enter Your Text ">
      <p id="para" class="okay"></p>
      <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Add Text</button>
      <button id="three" onclick="removeChild1()">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove the element, just clear its contents.

I'm not sure why you're doing `msgs.classList.add("okay")`, since it already has that class in the HTML.

```js
const inputVal = document.getElementById("two");
const txtr = document.getElementById("one");
const btnr = document.getElementById("btn");
const dlt = document.getElementById("three");

function myFunction() {
  if (inputVal.value == "") {
    var msgs = document.getElementById("para");
    msgs.innerHTML = "Enter Something Here ";
    msgs.classList.add("okay");
    setTimeout(() => msgs.innerHTML = "", 3000);
  } else {
    const x = document.createElement("li");
    x.setAttribute('id', "demo");
    var y = document.createTextNode(inputVal.value);
    x.appendChild(y);
    txtr.appendChild(x);
    inputVal.value = "";
  }
}

function removeChild1() {
  var item = document.getElementById('demo');
  txtr.removeChild(txtr.lastChild);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.input-values {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 10%;
}

.input-values h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightsalmon;
}

.second input {
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.second button {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border: 2px solid lightcoral;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
}

.okay {
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 520px;
  left: 310px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-values">
      <h1>Add Some Text</h1>
      <ol class="txt" id="one">
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <input type="text" name="" id="two" placeholder="Enter Your Text ">
      <p id="para" class="okay"></p>
      <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Add Text</button>
      <button id="three" onclick="removeChild1()">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```